# dplyr summarise Rle

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a basepair coverage of sequencing data in the following data:

```
chr    start      end               geneID score strand postion coverage
1  chr1  3054232  3054733 ENSMUSG00000090025.1     0      +       1        0
2  chr1  3054232  3054733 ENSMUSG00000090025.1     0      +       3        0
3  chr1  3054232  3054733 ENSMUSG00000090025.1     0      +       5        0
4  chr1  3054232  3054733 ENSMUSG00000090025.1     0      +       7        0
5  chr1  3054232  3054733 ENSMUSG00000090025.1     0      +       9        0
6  chrY 90838868 90839177 ENSMUSG00000096850.1     0      -     297        1
7  chrY 90838868 90839177 ENSMUSG00000096850.1     0      -     299        1
8  chrY 90838868 90839177 ENSMUSG00000096850.1     0      -     301        1
9  chrY 90838868 90839177 ENSMUSG00000096850.1     0      -     303        1
10 chrY 90838868 90839177 ENSMUSG00000096850.1     0      -     305        1
11 chrY 90838868 90839177 ENSMUSG00000096850.1     0      -     307        1
12 chrY 90838868 90839177 ENSMUSG00000096850.1     0      -     309        1
```

I am trying to use `dplyr` to get either a data frame, named list, or similar matching a "geneID" to the `Rle` of coverage. I have been trying variations on the below code, but can not get it to work. Does anyone have suggestions?

```
library(dplyr)
library(S4Vectors)    
group_by(df, geneID) %>% summarise(run_len = Rle(coverage))
```

Comment: Do you mean `rle` being from base R (run length encoding), or is `Rle` (capital R) something else?

Comment: This is the help file for Rle. "
Rle-class {S4Vectors} R Documentation
Rle objects

Description

The Rle class is a general container for storing an atomic vector that is stored in a run-length encoding format. It is based on the rle function from the base package." I think either would work, the GenomicRanges package does everything in Rle so that is what I have been using.

Comment: Yes, but what package is `Rle` from please? So that we may use it. Also, are you sure run-length is what you are after? at the moment all your run lengths will be 1 because no `coverage` is duplicated.

Comment: It is from the S4Vectors package in Bioconductor. I believe that Rle is what I am after. Say for the first gene "ENSMUSG00000090025.1" I currently have 5 rows in the data frame saying that coverage is 0. Instead I could store that as ` Rle(c(0,0,0,0,0)) ->
numeric-Rle of length 5 with 1 run
  Lengths: 5
  Values : 0 ` . As I go over the entire genome this greatly reduces the amount that needs to be stored.

Comment: Thanks. also apologies re: rle, I was looking at the 'position' column instead of the 'coverage' one (I didn't notice the titles don't quite match up with the data)

Answer (score 0):

Note - I'm using `rle` not `Rle` b ecause I don't have the S4Vectors package from Bioconductor, so if the output object is different you may need to modify it.

Note that since `rle` doesn't return a value that can be nicely "mushed" into a single cell in a dataframe (it stores the run value and the run length, and you might have several runs not just one per gene), you should get a list as an output instead of a dataframe.

You could do something like this with `plyr`

```
library(plyr)
# data is in x
o <- dlply(x, .(geneID), function (dd) rle(dd$coverage))
```

`o` is a list with some extra attributes. `names(o)` are the names of your genes; `o[[genename]]` is the output of `rle(x$coverage)` for that gene.

e.g.

```
o[[1]]
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int 5
  values : num 0
# o[[1]]$lengths gives the lengths of each run
# o[[1]]$values gives the values of each run.
```

Answer (score 0):

It sort of seems like you want to calculate coverage within each gene, rather than on each chromosome. So

```
library(GenomicRanges)
gr = with(df, GRanges(geneID, IRanges(postion, width=1),   
                      coverage=coverage))
coverage(gr, weight=gr$coverage)
```

giving

```
> gr
GRanges object with 12 ranges and 1 metadata column:
                   seqnames     ranges strand   |  coverage
                      <Rle>  <IRanges>  <Rle>   | <integer>
   [1] ENSMUSG00000090025.1     [1, 1]      *   |         0
   [2] ENSMUSG00000090025.1     [3, 3]      *   |         0
   [3] ENSMUSG00000090025.1     [5, 5]      *   |         0
   [4] ENSMUSG00000090025.1     [7, 7]      *   |         0
   [5] ENSMUSG00000090025.1     [9, 9]      *   |         0
   ...                  ...        ...    ... ...       ...
   [8] ENSMUSG00000096850.1 [301, 301]      *   |         1
   [9] ENSMUSG00000096850.1 [303, 303]      *   |         1
  [10] ENSMUSG00000096850.1 [305, 305]      *   |         1
  [11] ENSMUSG00000096850.1 [307, 307]      *   |         1
  [12] ENSMUSG00000096850.1 [309, 309]      *   |         1
  -------
  seqinfo: 2 sequences from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
> coverage(gr, weight=gr$coverage)
RleList of length 2
$ENSMUSG00000090025.1
integer-Rle of length 9 with 1 run
  Lengths: 9
  Values : 0

$ENSMUSG00000096850.1
integer-Rle of length 309 with 14 runs
  Lengths: 296   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
  Values :   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
```

Once you have the GRanges, you could use magrittr-pipes with

```
library(magrittr)
> library(magrittr)
> gr %>% coverage(weight="coverage")
RleList of length 2
$ENSMUSG00000090025.1
integer-Rle of length 9 with 1 run
  Lengths: 9
  Values : 0

$ENSMUSG00000096850.1
integer-Rle of length 309 with 14 runs
  Lengths: 296   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
  Values :   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
```

It might also make sense to use the `seqinfo=` argument to `GRanges()` to provide the widths of each of the genes (otherwise coverage is just to the last covered base, rather than to the end of the gene).

Generally, Bioconductor data objects do not play well with dplyr (as above, though, there is no problem using pipes `%>%`) and traditional `data.frame()` representations. This is because `data.frame()` and dplyr do not not implement a particular API (e.g., "any object with a `length()` and 1-dimensional `[` method can be a column). This implementation of data structures around APIs is a hallmark of the IRanges infrastructure in Bioconductor, e.g., the `DataFrame()` class behaves like a `data.frame()` but allows a column of any type so long as it implements `length()` and `[`.

A little speculatively, you might also find `?GenomicFeatures::mapToTranscripts` helpful for mapping between global coordinates (your start / end column) and local coordinates (postion).